# Error trying to use perl Regexp::Common::Net

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to parse all IPs from a text with Regexp::Common::Net as such :

```
use strict;
use Regexp::Common::net; 
if ($ids{$h} =~ /$RE{net}{IPv4}/) {
    print $1;
}
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Global symbol "%RE" requires explicit package name at example.pl
```

I have also tried:

```
if ($ids{$h} =~ $RE{net}{IPv4})
```

and

```
if ($ids{$h} =~ m/$RE{net}{IPv4}/)
```

with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

`use Regexp::Common::net;` was wrong. After changing it to `use Regexp::Common 'net';` I stopped having that error.

EDIT: To work, the snippet above, the regex needs to be: /$RE{net}{IPv4}{-keep}/

Comment: It is quite common to write `use Regexp::Common qw(net)`. The advantage of this approach is that you can import more than one symbol in the same line, e.g. `use Regexp::Common qw(net CC)`

Comment: Great. I am learning perl in a hurry, for professional reasons and I have wondered about the qw() statements but I haven't got around to learn them

Comment: `qw` generates a list from each separate word in the string, so my previous example would be equivalent to `use Regexp::Common ("net", "CC")`. I would recommend checking out the documentation on [quotes and quote-like operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)

Comment: That's a really neat way to declare an array.